# *.bat that save path folder as variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I try to do a little tool in *.bat but I didn't found an answer like I am looking for.
The idea is by double clicking to the script, a window popup to select a folder and save the path folder as a kind of "variable" and put it inside a string as shown as below.
I would like to unzip recursively from multiple directory and sub-directory.

```
@echo off
Title unzip_bz2
for /r "%Location%" %I IN (*.bz2) DO 7z x %I -o"%~dpI"
```

to have something like:

```
FOR /R C:\Users\steph\Desktop\my_bz2_file\ %I IN (*.bz2) DO 7z x %I -o"%~dpI"
```

Thanks in advance for your advise and help.

Comment: `cmd` has `%CD%` that returns the full path of the current directory...

Comment: I would love to have the possibility to select the main directory, wherever it is located and not to be specifically inside.

Comment: Use `%%I` instead of `%I` in a batch file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could utilise [jscript](/questions/tagged/jscript) from your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to help you with this task:

```bat
0</* :
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In (
    '""%__APPDIR__%cscript.exe" //E:JScript //NoLogo "%~f0" 2>Nul|Find /V """'
)Do @For /F "Delims=" %%H In ('Dir /B/S/A-D "%%G\*.bz2" 2^>NUL')Do @7z.exe x "%%H" -o"%%~dpH"
@Exit /B */0;
var Folder=new ActiveXObject('Shell.Application').BrowseForFolder(0,'Select your directory.',1,'0');
try{new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(Folder.Self.Path)};catch(e){};close();
```

Obviously for this to work using your provided `7z` command, `7z.exe` must be in the current directory, located within `%PATH%`, or its location specified in the relevant registry key. If not you'd need to provide the full path to `7z.exe`

Comment: This command works perfectly with the first code you gave:
`0</* :
@For /F "EOL=|Delims=" %%G In (
    '""%__APPDIR__%cscript.exe" //E:JScript //NoLogo "%~f0" 2>Nul|Find /V """'
)Do @For /F %%H In ('Dir /B/S/A-D "%%G\*.bz2"')Do @7z x "%%H" -o"%%~dpH"
@Exit /B */0;
` 
Thanks a lot for this tips.Now I have a second question. 
If I want to add a command to unzip *.tar just right after the first treatment, how do I do ?

Comment: If I want to add a command to unzip *.tar just right after the first treatment, how do I do ? Actually, I am using CALL to do the second step.

Comment: Why are you using the code I have since improved, I edited it because of potential issues, please try the code above instead. Why would you be using `Call`? Is the second step another batch file? Or is it another label within the same batch file? `Call` is not used for `.exe` files! Also, I have answered the unclear question you asked, this site is not here to do your work for you, and it's intention is not for multiple issues per post. You either need an ampersand to separate your `Do` commands, or parenthesise them and separate them with a new line instead.

Comment: I kept the first code because it's perfectly suited to my environment. :-)
I am usually developing stuff under Linux environment for more than 15 years but today I am asked to do the same tasks under "Windows".
I have a lot of difficulty understanding the "batch" syntax, even despite my many readings, therefore I am struggling to ask my questions clearly.
I do not ask anyone to do my job but ask a community to help and who has more experience than me in using batch ... Most probably my mistaken?
Yes, I use "call" to add a second step to my treatment.

Comment: The first code, was improved because it had unnecessary parts, and had an issue which meant it would fail in some circumstances. Just to clarify my previous comment, `Call "file.exe"` is absolutely incorrect; `Call "batch.file" [args]`, `Call :BatchFileLabel [args]`, and `Call InternalCommand ...` are how to use the `Call` command.